# Shiny deployApp vs Publish button?

Tags: r, shiny

1. Is there any difference using **Publish button** on top of code window in RStudio versus the **`deployapp()`** from shinyapps package?
2. Can you use these two methods interchangeably?

I used the Publish button, but now I want to run a script to update my deployment when I get new data.

*I am getting Internal Server Errors when running deployApp, which may be coincidental to new shiny rollout and not symptomatic of mixing Publish/deployApp()*

> Error: /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:28572&filter=name: ....path/myapp&count=100&offset=0 500 - Internal Server Error

Looking at logs using:

```
shinyapps::showLogs(account = "xyz", appName = myapp)
```

says [stuff deleted]:

```
2015-05-26T.. shinyapps[-----]: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:47030

2015-05-26T.. shinyapps[-----]: Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package
‘RJSONIO’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘jsonlite’: not turning on duplicate class
definitions for this class.
```

Since app seems to deploy ok, should one ignore Internal errors...?

Comment: The RJSONIO error was due to a missing `library(shiny)` in global.R. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181212/r-package-with-dependency-on-shiny-gives-rjsonio-warning